# What other BLDC form factors are out there and similar to Pancake style BLDCs?

Tags: motor, torque, brushless-motor, bldc

What other form factors of BLDC motors are there which I should consider?  I need to try to stay as compact as possible in at least one axis (like is accomplished by a pancake motor).  I specifically need a 1Nm nominal torque, 12V (or so), pancake style (or similar) BLDC motor.